# Plot mesh from .obj file using plotly.graph_objs

Tags: python, plotly

I have a mesh stored in an obj file and I need to plot it using `plotly.graph_objs`. Is there a way I can do it? I need to use `graph_objs` because I need to display the mesh together with some scatter plot.

You can download the Stanford bunny from [here](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/stanford-bunny-43f266d6cd6e4c6888b9943557528c0f).

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59923419/pyopengl-how-do-i-import-an-obj-file ?

Comment: If you can use it in python, that means you can use it with Plotly.

Answer (score 1):

An `obj` file can be read with `meshio`, https://github.com/nschloe/meshio. Once the mesh has been read, you can extract the triangles and the triangle vertex coordinates, from which you can get  data to be passed to the constructor of the  Plotly `go.Mesh3d` class. This notebook https://nbviewer.org/github/empet/Hollow-mask-illusion/blob/main/Hollow-Mask-illusion-Animation.ipynb illustrates both a triangulated mesh, and a filled mesh.